# Makefile: no rule to make target

Tags: c++, c, build, makefile

I was looking for a solution on this site and also tried google for some time now, but somehow I can't get it to work.

My source should be in the src directory and the object files would be in the obj directory. Now I try to create a simple makefie but I either get an error that there is no rule, or I can't make it work to use the directories.

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

SRC:=       nohupshd.cpp \
            task.cpp

OBJ:=       nohupshd.o \
            task.o

OBJDIR:=        obj
SRCDIR:=        src

DEP:=       src/task.h
LIBS:=

TARGET:=    nohupshd

all:    $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ) $(LIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(TARGET)
```

Variant 1:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -S $(SRCDIR)/$< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
    $(CC) -c $(SRCDIR)/$< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

Variant 1a:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) -S $(SRCDIR)/$< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
    $(CC) -c $(SRCDIR)/$< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

When I use this pattern I always get an error that there is no rule for nohupshd.o to build.

Variant 2:

```
$(OBJ) : $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -S $(SRCDIR)/$< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
    $(CC) -c $(SRCDIR)/$< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

When I use this variant, I can see that it tries to build, but I get errors saying that "file".o doesn't fit the target pattern.

Another issue is that "$<" doesn't give me the source name. According to several sites it should, but I can see in the output that there is nothing, so how  can I fix this?

Update:

In the meantime my newest version looks like this:

```
$(OBJDIR)/$(OBJ) : $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -S $< -o $(OBJDIR)/`basename $@ .o`.asm
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

This now manages to compile the first objectfile (nohupshd.o) but when make tries to do the second file it fails again saying: target 'task.o' doesn't match a pattern.

Comment: At least now I understand a part the real problem. The object files are in the obj directory. When I put as the dependency $(OBJDIR)/$(OBJ) then this expands to obj/o1.o   o2.o ... while what it should be is obj/o1.o obj/o2.o ..., So do I have to specify the obj path really on each individual file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found the answer on how to write this makefile, for an exaplanation of my mistakes look at the posting I marked as correct answer:

The resulting makefile looks like this, and for completeness I post it here including dependencies for header files (remove the ASM parts if you don't need 'em):

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .o .cpp
.SUFFIXES: .o .d

CC := g++
LNK:= ar
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

OBJDIR:=        obj
SRCDIR:=        src
HDIR:=      include

INCLUDE_PATHS:= -Iinclude -Iinclude/interfaces -Iinclude/support

CPP_FILES := propertyfile/propertyfile.cpp \
            propertyfile/propertyitem.cpp \
            propertyfile/propertyfactory.cpp

OBJ :=  $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(CPP_FILES))
SRC :=  $(patsubst %.cpp,$(SRCDIR)/%.o, $(CPP_FILES))
ASM :=      $(patsubst %.cpp, $(OBJDIR)/$*.asm, $(CPP_FILES))

LIBS:=      

TARGET:=    libsupport.a

all:    $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):  $(OBJ)
    @echo "Linking..."
    @$(LNK) rvs $(TARGET) $(OBJ)
    @cp $(TARGET) ../lib
    @cp -r include ..

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ) $(ASM) $(TARGET)

-include $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(CPP_FILES))

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(OBJDIR)/%.d 
    @mkdir -p `dirname $@`
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -S $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$*.asm $(INCLUDE_PATHS)
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDE_PATHS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.d: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -MM -MT $@ -MF $(OBJDIR)/$*.d -c $< $(INCLUDE_PATHS)
```

I hope this helps other user. All examples that I found were either extremly simple and listed multiple files individually and not part of a rule, but didn't really explain how it works, or were so complicated that I couldn't find out how it can help me.

Answer (score 7):

You actually have a couple if incorrect things above.

First you write *My error was, that I was assuming that the pattern %.o matches ANY pattern ending with .o which it doesn't*; that's not true.  The pattern *does* match any string ending in `.o`.  However, the pattern character `%` that is matched on the target side is replaced on the prerequisite side with the identical string.  So if you have a target `obj/task.o` and it matches the pattern `%.o` then the *stem* (what the manual calls it) will be `obj/task`, and when the prerequisite is `%.c` that means that make will look for a prerequisite `obj/task.c`.  Since there isn't one, and make doesn't know how to build one, that rule is discarded as not applying.  When writing pattern rules you must write them so *ONLY* the identical parts of the names match the pattern character (`%`).  ALL non-identical parts, including directories, must be specified explicitly.

Second, the rule `$(OBJ) : $(SRC)` is really not right.  That line says that each object file depends on *all* the source files, so whenever any single source file changes `all` the object files will be recompiled.  That's really not what you want (if that IS what you want you don't need make: you can just write a simple shell script).  I don't know what you mean by *since the rules is empty it invokes the pattern rule*; you don't need this to invoke the pattern rule.  The target depends on `$(OBJ)`, and each object file depends on its source file (due to the pattern).  You don't need this line at all.

Third, I don't know why you are trying to construct .asm files rather than just compiling directly from source to object, but if you really want them it would be cleaner and more "make-like" to create a separate pattern rule to build them: create a pattern rule `$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(OBJDIR)/%.asm` and a rule `$(OBJDIR)/%.asm : $(SRCDIR)/%.c`.  If you want the ASM files to be products of the build you should declare them as a prerequisite of `all` or similar, otherwise they'll be deleted as intermediate files.

Fourth, using things like `basename` is unnecessary.  There are lots of automatic make variables that can be used instead.  For example, `$*` expands to the stem, so you could write `$(OBJDIR)/$*.asm`.  Of course if you make a separate pattern rule for ASM files you can just use `$@` or `$<` directly.  There are various make functions that can also be used; see the manual.

Fifth, you define a variable containing a header file, `DEP`, but then never use it.  Because it's not used, if you change that file nothing would be rebuilt.  If you know that all the source files include every header you can use `$(OBJ) : $(DEP)` to define that; but it does mean (as in the second point above) that any change to any header causes all objects to recompile.  You would be better off auto-generating the prerequisites; since you're using GCC this is quite simple.

Sixth, you're using C++ files (xxx.cpp) but you're using the C compiler.  This will not work (the link line will fail: although the compiler can see you're compiling a C++ file and do the right thing, even if you call gcc, when you link a bunch of objects together it has no idea if those were C objects or C++ objects (or FORTRAN or whatever) so you MUST use the C++ front-end to link or it won't pull in the right C++ libraries).  You should be using the make variable `CXX` to build C++ code, not `CC`, and setting it to `g++` not `gcc`.

Seventh, you don't need `.SUFFIXES: .c .o` to use pattern rules.  They are only needed for suffix rules, which you don't have here.  You can keep the plain `.SUFFIXES:` though to disable built-in pattern matching which is a slight performance improvement.

Finally, you'll note you don't actually need the `$(SRC)` variable because make can infer it from the pattern rules.  However, if you wanted to have your makefile less onerous to change, you could construct the contents of the OBJ variable from the SRC variable, like `SRC = nohupshd.cpp task.cpp` then `OBJ = $(patsubst %.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRC))`.

So, all-in, this is how I would recommend you write your makefile (I don't include the auto-generated dependencies here though):

```
.SUFFIXES:

CXX :=      g++
CXXFLAGS := -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0

OBJDIR :=   obj
SRCDIR :=   src

TARGET :=   nohupshd
SRC :=      nohupshd.cpp task.cpp
DEP :=      src/task.h
LIBS :=

# ----

OBJ :=      $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SRC))
ASM :=      $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.asm,$(SRC))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET) $(ASM)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)

clean:
        rm -f $(OBJDIR)/* $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.asm
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -x assembler-with-cpp $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.asm : $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -S $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about patterns. This really helped a lot. In your example there is a small bug because you wrote in the pattern substition "*.c" instead of "*.cpp" but that's a minor issue. The asm I left as it is, because I don't want to have a seperate rule for this. I prefer to have the asm output generated, so I can check what the compiler is really doing. :) Most users can simply remove that. If I would create a seperate rule, I would have to compile to asm to object in seperate steps which doesn't make sense here. I update my above posting with the working version now. Thanks!

Comment: Of course do it how you like.  The problem with your solution is you're significantly increasing your build time, because you're running the majority of the compiler work twice.  Once the assembly is available it's almost no work to convert it into object files: most of the effort is in the preprocessing, parsing, and especially optimizing to generate assembly.  If you want assembly output the most efficient way is to first generate the assembly then compile the _assembly_ into the object file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't repeat the directory names in the compiler line. `$<` and `$@` already have the directory names.

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) -S $< -o $@
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Yeah, I found this out in the meantime, but that doesn't solve the rest of the problem.

Comment: You have to change `OBJ` so that the object files have the `$(OBJDIR)` prefix.  You're not asking for `obj/task.o` to be built, you're asking for just `task.o` to be built.  Make does not guess that maybe you really meant some other file.  If you want to build a file, then the target must be _that_ filename, exactly.  And the prerequisite must be _that_ filename, exactly.

Comment: Yeah, after lots of fiddling, I finally found out how the makefile must look like. Unfortunately I found lots of examples, but all were either oversimple or overcomplicated. I'm surprised that such a common thing is not easily found with a working real world example.