# Write a one make file to compile a project wihich has both source codes and header files in different directories

Tags: c, shell, unix, gcc, makefile

I am trying to write a Makefile script for a provided directory structure and list of files by my clients. below image shows the roughly how source files and header files located in the main directory of the project.

```
rootDir/
-lib/
  -socketserver/
-dist/
  -bin/

-include/
  -abms_engine_socket_server/
    -abms_engine_socket_server.h
    -common/
      -----
    -hashtable/
      -----
-src/
  -abms_engine_socket_server/
    -Makefile
    -abms_engine_socket_server.c
    -common/
      -----
    -hashtable/
      -----
```

In this case below are the build target directories

library file dir: (rootDir)/lib/socketserver
bin file dir:     (rootDir)/dist/bin/abms_engine_socket_server
make file dir:    (rootDir)/src/abms_engine_socket_server
include files and source files also located within "include" and "src" directories.

I already try with below script to compile the entire source files.

```
HEADER_DIR = ../../include/abms_engine_socket_server
HEADER_COMMON_DIR = $(HEADER_DIR)/common
HEADER_HASHTABLE_DIR = $(HEADER_DIR)/hashtable

SRC_DIR = ..
SRC_COMMON_DIR = $(SRC_DIR)/common
SRC_HASHTABLE_DIR = $(SRC_DIR)/hashtable
OBJ_DIR = ../../lib/socketserver
DEST_DIR = ../../dist/bin
SRC = abms_engine_socket_server.c

CC = gcc -g -std=gnu99 -DUNIX -DINTERNAL_LOGGER
CFLAGS = -lm

PROG_ENG_SOCKET_SVR = $(DEST_DIR)/abms_engine_socket_server

HASHTABLE_OBJS = $(OBJ_DIR)/hashtable.o $(OBJ_DIR)/hashtable_itr.o $(OBJ_DIR)/hashtable_utility.o
COMMON_OBJS = $(OBJ_DIR)/CUtil.o $(OBJ_DIR)/CConfig.o $(OBJ_DIR)/CSocket.o

#Compiler to compile the hashtable objects
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_HASHTABLE_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

#Compiler to compile the common objects which have header files too
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_COMMON_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

#Compiler to compile the process objects which do not have header files
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@

#Compiler to compile the other binaries
$(DEST_DIR)/% : $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o $(HASHTABLE_OBJS) $(COMMON_OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(HASHTABLE_OBJS) $(COMMON_OBJS) $< -o $@

#all: $(PROG_ENG_SOCKET_SVR)
all: $(SRC) $(PROG_ENG_SOCKET_SVR)

clean:
    rm -f *~ $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(PROG_ENG_SOCKET_SVR)
```

But finally I am getting bellow error
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

Please instruct me to create this make file to compile these sources using single make file. All responses are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you `make clean`, and then `make ../../lib/socketserver/abms_engine_socket_server.o`?

Comment: @Beta,
I just tried it and gave below output. 
----------------------------------------------
>>$ make
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
>>$ make clean
rm -f *~ ../../lib/socketserver/*.o ../../dist/bin/abms_engine_socket_server
rm: cannot remove `../../dist/bin/abms_engine_socket_server': Is a directory
make: *** [clean] Error 1
-------------------------------------------------
According to this, I think the build destination also should be changed in the Make file.

Comment: Your description of the directory structure is inconsistent in the use of slashes. Both `include/abms_engine_socket_server` and `src/abms_engine_socket_server` appear to be directories, though they have no slashes. But `dist/bin/abms_engine_socket_server/` has a slash, even though the Makefile treats it as a target file. If it is a directory, I suggest you remove it and try again.

Comment: @Beta, 
I just removed "abms_engine_socket_server" from destination directory in the directory structure and put try again without making any changes on Makefile. Then it is hitting this error(for make all) "make: *** No rule to make target `../../dist/bin/abms_engine_socket_server', needed by `all'.  Stop.
"

Comment: **What happens when you make clean, and then make ../../lib/socketserver/abms_engine_socket_server.o?**

Comment: Object files are not creating at all.
--- 
[..]$ make clean
rm -f *~ ../../lib/socketserver/*.o ../../dist/bin/abms_engine_socket_server
[..]$ make
make: *** No rule to make target `../../dist/bin/abms_engine_socket_server', needed by `all'.  Stop.

Comment: I have an idea of what's wrong, but I can't confirm it without your help, and I'm not going to write a full answer on a guess.

Comment: Yes understood, Just give me a suggestion about my mistakes in Makefile. I will try to correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have a rather similar structure, so yo can take a look at my makefile which I documented here if it is of help to you.

[Makefile: no rule to make target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084456/makefile-no-rule-to-make-target)

You must look at the accepted answer, that's the one containing my working version.