# GTK+ gcc: undefined reference to all gtk functions when linking

Tags: c, linker, compiler-errors, gtk

I'm coding an interface with GTK+ for chat using XMPP protocol.
My code worked fine when I compiled it like :

```
gcc login_gtk.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

But since I add my file to my project, and I'm using a Makefile, it doesn't compile anymore. I guess the problem comes from my Makefile.

Compiler errors :

```
gcc -o -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./Includes/. -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0     -c -o Sources/login_gtk.o Sources/login_gtk.c
gcc -o -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./Includes/. -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0     -c -o Sources/circular_buffer.o Sources/circular_buffer.c
gcc -o -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./Includes/. -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0     -c -o Sources/welcome_server.o Sources/welcome_server.c
gcc -o -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./Includes/. -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0     -c -o Sources/main_loop.o Sources/main_loop.c
gcc -o -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./Includes/. -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0     -c -o Sources/client_init.o Sources/client_init.c
gcc -o -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./Includes/. -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0     -c -o Sources/main.o Sources/main.c
gcc -o x2p ./Sources/login_gtk.o ./Sources/circular_buffer.o ./Sources/welcome_server.o ./Sources/main_loop.o ./Sources/client_init.o ./Sources/main.o -lexpat
./Sources/login_gtk.o: In function `login_form':
./Sources/login_gtk.c:10: undefined reference to `gtk_entry_new'
./Sources/login_gtk.c:11: undefined reference to `gtk_entry_get_type'
./Sources/login_gtk.c:11: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
./Sources/login_gtk.c:11: undefined reference to `gtk_entry_set_text'
./Sources/login_gtk.c:12: undefined reference to `gtk_box_get_type'
./Sources/login_gtk.c:12: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
./Sources/login_gtk.c:12: undefined reference to `gtk_box_pack_start'
./Sources/login_gtk.c:13: undefined reference to `gtk_entry_get_type'
./Sources/login_gtk.c:13: undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
```

Makefile:

```
NAME            =       x2p

SRCS            =                                   \
                    ./Sources/login_gtk.c           \
                    ./Sources/circular_buffer.c     \
                    ./Sources/welcome_server.c      \
                    ./Sources/main_loop.c           \
                    ./Sources/client_init.c         \
                    ./Sources/main.c                \                                                                                                      
OBJS            =       $(SRCS:.c=.o)

CC              =       gcc -o

CFLAGS          =       -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./Includes/. $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)

LDFLAGS         +=      -lexpat

RM              =       rm -f

CAR             =       *\# *~ *core*

all             :       $(NAME)

$(NAME)         :       $(OBJS)
                        $(CC) $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
clean           :
                        $(RM) $(OBJS) $(CAR)

fclean          :       clean
                        $(RM) $(NAME)

re              :       fclean all
```

And part of login_gtk.c:

```
#include        <gtk/gtk.h>


void            location_form(GtkWidget *pVBox)
{
  GtkWidget     *pList;

  pList = gtk_combo_box_text_new();
  gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(pList), "LOCATION");
  gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(pList), "WORK");
  gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(pList), "HOME");
  gtk_combo_box_text_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX_TEXT(pList), "SCHOOL");
  gtk_combo_box_set_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(pList), 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(pVBox), pList, FALSE, TRUE, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order [is wrong](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-l-1133): this is an incredibly common mistake I continue to meet. Previous versions of `gcc` were less picky on the argument order and this spread the wrong idea `pkgconfig --cflags --libs` works in every position.

Check out [this email](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2010-February/msg00035.html) for info on proper flags ordering. In short:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags ...) myapp.c $(pkg-config --libs ...)
```

Comment: It's also worth adding that even with a single file, some platforms require the source files to be listed before the `pkg-config` insert. Debian lets me do _gcc `pkg-config --blah` test.c_, but indeed, MSYS2/`mingw-w64` requires _gcc test.c `pkg-config --blah`_ ...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included the libraries in your Makefile.

You must add `-L<path to your lib directory` and `-lgtk+-3.0` to your linker line.

`CLFAGS` missing here ...

```
$(NAME)         :       $(OBJS)
                    $(CC) $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

or here:

```
LDFLAGS         +=      -lexpat
```

Comment: That is the job of `$(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)`

Comment: But your linker line shows that this doesn't happen. The first line of your compiler errors shows nothing about the libraries. In your linker line you don't pass the CFLAGS.

Comment: It actually does work, I've edited the post. I added the first line of the compilation. But I guess it just an order issuer in the linking process.

Comment: Like `gcc login_gtk.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)` does work. But `gcc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0) login_gtk.c` does not work. But I don't know how to manage this behaviour in my Makefile

Comment: Yes, that would have been my next guess, but since your line didn't show it it was seemingly an obvious thing. If it worked before, then why not look at what is different now in your linker line?

Answer (score 0):

I finally reach to compile by doing this thing the Makefile :

```
NAME            =       x2p

SRCS            =                                       \
                        ./Sources/circular_buffer.c     \
                        ./Sources/welcome_server.c      \
                        ./Sources/main_loop.c           \
                        ./Sources/client_init.c         \
                        ./Sources/main.c                \                                            

OBJS            =       $(SRCS:.c=.o)

LLFLAGS         =       $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)

CC              =       gcc

O               =       -o

CFLAGS          =       -W -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g -I./Includes/.


LDFLAGS         +=      -lexpat

RM              =       rm -f

CAR             =       *\# *~ *core*

all             :       $(NAME)

$(NAME)         :       $(OBJS)
                        $(CC) -I./Includes/. ./Sources/login_gtk.c $(LLFLAGS) $(O) $(NAME) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
clean           :
                        $(RM) $(OBJS) $(CAR)

fclean          :       clean
                        $(RM) $(NAME)

re              :       fclean all
```

Comment: Thats what I already told you in my answer, only giving it a new variable name. ;)

Comment: I haven't understood that way. But actually I'm not really satisfied by this way, because I'll havve many c files will need to be compile with the librabry. And I won't put them all that way ! That's dirty.

Comment: You can write a makefile rule, so you don't have to edit it whenever you need to add a new source file. Also you probably don't have depencies when include file changes. You could take a look here, where I posted my working makefile as a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084456/makefile-no-rule-to-make-target