# MinGW gtk undefined reference

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, gtk, mingw

I currently need to compile GTK+ application for Windows. My makefile looks like this:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -m32 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Werror `pkg-config.exe --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
LDFLAGS=-m32 `pkg-config.exe --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
SOURCES=$(wildcard src/*.cpp)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=screenplay

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Where pkg-config.exe should give me correct -I and -L parameters (e.g. path where include files and library files are located). Not surprising it actually gives them - the output is:

```
-mms-bitfields -IC:/MinGW/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/MinGW/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/MinGW/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/MinGW/include/cairo -IC:/MinGW/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/MinGW/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/MinGW/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/MinGW/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/MinGW/include -IC:/MinGW/include/freetype2 -IC:/MinGW/include/libpng14  -LC:/MinGW/lib -lgtk-win32-2.0 -lgdk-win32-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

I can confirm that libs are present at the location (C:/MinGW/lib/), yet I receive undefined reference errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a good reason you write a `Makefile` yourself? Is CMake out of the picture?

Comment: Pasting the resulting compilation command lines and the actual errors you are getting is likely going to be helpful in getting your problem solved.

Comment: Classical call of `make` - compilation is successful, linking is the problem. Basically what I call:
g++ -m32 `pkg-config.exe --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` ALL_OBJECTS -o EXECUTABLE_NAMEz

I receive undefined reference to gtk_main (and few others), like I wouldn't even link the libraries at linking step.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GTK+ gcc: undefined reference to all gtk functions when linking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124070/gtk-gcc-undefined-reference-to-all-gtk-functions-when-linking)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked where the gtk libraries are actually installed? You seem to only have `-LC:/MinGW/lib` for you library path are you sure all the libraries are in there? By the way I think you only need to pass `--cflags` to pkg-config to set `CFLAGS` and `--libs` to set `LDFLAGS` you don't need both.